# why did my vs code turn orange and how can i fix this?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

[image: how it looks like]

This has happened during a group project (We're students) and this must've happened with all the pushing and pulling from git But I don't know how to fix it (The orange borders)

Comment: do you have the same behavior with `VSC Insiders` without any setting changed and without any extension installed

Comment: @rioV8 only this project

Comment: what if you rename the `.vscode` folder

Answer (score 0):

try changing your theme by pressing ctrl+t

Comment: It's not the theme, if it was i wouldn't ask this question here

Comment: it is not `Ctrl+T`